# is_admin() triggers error

Tags: wp-admin, conditional-tags

I've a plugin which includes other files and it looks like that :

```
if( is_admin() ) {

    require( DIR.  'file.php' );
}
```

In this file I run a class. This class is initialized on `plugins_loaded`.

The problem is is_admin() return false for my include but true for the init class so I get a fatal error because class is loaded while it does not exist

It's probably due to the fact I'm using a conditional tag without any context, isn't it?

**EDIT** : the class is initialized on `plugins_loaded` with a condition `is_admin()`

Comment: On which hook was initialed the check for `is_admin()`, that will include the additional file?

Comment: Please show some more code on how you are using the above functionality.